# jQuery ancestors

Tags: jquery

Is there an easier way to say

```
$('element').parent('parentElement').parent('grandParentElement');
```

**Answer**: Try *parents*() or *closest*()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('element').closest('grandParentElement');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('element').parent().parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('element').parents('grandParentElement');`

Notice **"parents"** and not "parent"